# angular2, why is this html5 validation not working in and out of ngForm

Tags: javascript, html, validation, angular

I've created a plunkr to demonstrate the issue. Basically there are three `<input type="text">` elements with html5 `pattern` attribute set to `^\d{2}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}$` on all of them. Difference between these three textboxes is that one is directly inside a `<form>`, another is inside a child component and that's inside the `<form>` tag. The last textbox is entirely outside of `<form>` and i'm expecting all three of them to behave the same on pattern validation as they all have Angular2 classes (`ng-touched`, `ng-invalid`, etc...) set, which tells me they're Angular2 controls. However, issue is that they are never set to `ng-valid` and always remain `ng-invalid` even when input value is `99/99/9999` which according to following regex websites is a valid match:

1. [regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95455)
2. [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3du7k)

Interestingly, `ng-untouched` and `ng-pristine` do update to proper classes when textboxes receive or lose focus. So what am I missing here? Why is input pattern change doesn't update the css class to be `ng-valid`? Here's the plunkr I mentioned: https://plnkr.co/edit/kW861I8OdnO9iR0328KP?p=preview

**Update**

If any of these textboxes are placed outside the `<my-app>` aka root element, they work just fine and browser validation seems to recognize the pattern to be valid. I've updated the plunkr with `txt 4`.

Comment: give it a try http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

Comment: @rashfmnb that's declarative approach and my solution is built using html5 validation. It's a lot more complicated than a few textboxes, I made this to demonstrate the issue. It works in some places but not in above case, so not quite sure how it's supposed to behave.

Comment: actually i also tried to use textboxes in start but end up with the above link it think it is not supported by angular right now might be in final release. i marked your question as favourite so i might get enlighten by some one else answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plunker uses old forms module (tried few workarounds - did not help), i've checked with new module - it works. Check official doc and add the following:

```
    bootstrap(Application, [
    ...
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    ...
    ]);
```

Comment: I was in the middle of setting up a new dummy project to try the new RC.4 as i had a hunch this is the case. Unfortunately, i used `AnimationBuilder` and css transitions which seems to have vanished in RC.4 and hence couldn't upgrade to that. Only to hope if that class was available.